# In the consortium, level 2 of Starfront Collision - how to get/pass the stealth'ed monsters

Tags: starfront-collisions

In the iOS/Gameloft game, Starfront: Collisions, I have just started it and in level 2 of the Consortium campaign, you have to take out/over a radar - but it's protected by some stealthed monsters that we don't seem to be able to attack.

Here is me getting wiped again:

[image]

The game suggests some lander vehicle but that gets wiped as soon as it gets near them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need a Lancer, plus your normal soldiers.  The Lancer unit can 'detect' the invisible units, which will allow your normal soldiers to kill it.  However, by itself the detector unit will not be strong enough to defeat the invisible enemies.